# Pandas regex, replace group with char

Tags: python, regex, pandas

## Problem

How to replace X with _, given the following dataframe:

```py
data = {'street':['13XX First St', '2XXX First St', '47X Second Ave'], 
        'city':['Ashland', 'Springfield', 'Ashland']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The streets need to be edited, replacing each X with an underscore _.

*Notice that the number of Integers changes, as does the number of Xs. Also, street names such as Xerxes should not be edited to _er_es, but rather left unedited. Only the street number section should change.*

## Desired Output

```py
data = {'street':['13__ First St', '2___ First St', '47_ Second Ave'], 
        'city':['Ashland', 'Springfield', 'Ashland']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Progress

Some potential regex building blocks include:
1. [0-9]+ to capture numbers
2. X+ to capture Xs
3. ([0-9]+)(X+) to capture groups

```py
df['street']replace("[0-9]+)(X+)", value=r"\2", regex=True, inplace=False)
```

I'm pretty weak with regex, so my approach may not be the best. Preemptive thank you for any guidance or solutions!

Comment: you want to `_` with the number of times X appears? is if it was `13XXX` then you want `13___` (three underscores) ?

Comment: @Datanovice exactly so, 2 X should be replaced by 2 _. X -> _, XX -> __, XXX -> ___.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, this would do:

```
def repl(m):
    return m.group(1) + '_'*len(m.group(2))

df['street'].str.replace("^([0-9]+)(X*)", repl)
```

Output:

```
0     13__ First St
1     2___ First St
2    47_ Second Ave
Name: street, dtype: object
```

Comment: i couldn't get a function to work in `df.replace` - do you know why? it replaces the entire string with `<function repl at 0x000001C242C68268>`

Comment: You need `.str.replace`, which accepts a function, not `replace`.

Comment: that's right, but if you wanted to make the change across the entire dataframe you would need to loop through every column to use `str.replace` right?

Comment: Yes, or `df.apply(lamba x: x.str.replace(...)`

Comment: This is correct you need the str.replace to run this. It wont take just df.replace. Good work around

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, we can pass a function into the `repl` argument much like `re.sub`

```
def repl(m):
    return '_' * len(m.group())

df['street'].str.replace(r'([X])+',repl)
```

---

```
out:

0     13__ First St
1     2___ First St
2    47_ Second Ave
Name: street, dtype: object
```

if you need to match only after numbers, we can add a `'\d{1}'` which will only match after a single instance of `X`

```
df['street'].str.replace(r'\d{1}([X]+)+',repl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'X' only occurs in the 'street' column

```
streetresult=re.sub('X','_',str(df['street']))
```

Your desired output should be the result

Code I tested

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'street':['13XX First St', '2XXX First St', '47X Second Ave'], 
        'city':['Ashland', 'Springfield', 'Ashland']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
for  i in data:
    streetresult=re.sub('X','_',str(df['street']))
print(streetresult)
```

Comment: This will replace `X` in `123 Xmas Street` as well.

Comment: This is correct, setting the regex rules of if it following a $\d (numeric value) or an $'X' should account for street names such as that. If I'm not mistaken

Comment: @SublimizeD sorry, I hadn't made that clarification in the problem, but Quang's correct in pointing out that requirement. I'll edit the problem. Thank you!